# Ideal of $ \Bbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Assume that J is an ideal of $ \Bbb Z$. Prove that there exists $n \in J $ such that J=(n)

Not sure how to prove it. Any help is appropriated.

Comment: What are your ideas about the problem? Hint: if this element $n$ exists, you can assume it is $n>0$ (otherwise $J=\{0\}$, which is a trivial case). Can you guess what element it must be then?

Comment: Mmmmm is it n=1?

Comment: @NadiaC If such $n>0$ exists, can it be $m\in J$ with $0<m<n$? So, if there is $n>0$ with $J=(n)$, then $n$ must be the minimum positive element in $J$ and you can follow the given answers.

Answer (score 4):

It is enough to prove that every additive subgroup $J$ of $\mathbb Z$ is of the form $J=n\mathbb Z$ for some integer $n$. (Why is the additive subgroup $n\mathbb Z$ the same as the ideal $(n)$? And why is it OK to just make this argument of additive subgroups?)

Now let's prove the above claim. Let $J<\mathbb Z$. Let $a$ be the least positive element of $J$ (why does such an $a$ exist?). To show that every element of $J$ is a multiple of $a$, we suppose for contradiction that there exists some $b\in J$ is not a multiple of $a$. Since $b$ is not a multiple of $a$, we can divide $b$ by $a$, and see that $b=aq+r$ with $r<a$. Since $r$ is a nonzero element of $J$ (Why is it in $J$? Why is it not $0$?), we have just contradicted our choice of $a$, so there cannot be such a $b$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**: let $J\neq 0$ be any ideal and argue that there has to be a smallest positive element $b$ of $J$. Use the division algorithm to argue that any other element $a\in J$ can be written as $a=q\cdot b+ r$ where $0\leq r<b$. What can now be said about $r$?